# How to download source distribution from pypi using pip?

Tags: python, pip

I am creating a tool that analyzes a set of python package's source distributions. I am wondering if it is possible to use pip (or any other module) to download the source distribution tarball without installing or building it. I am going to process a lot of source distributions making manually downloading them individually from pypi.org a very tedious solution. Essentially I want something like:

```
>pip download_sdist foo
Successfully downloaded foo-1.2.3.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pip3 download --no-deps --no-binary :all: {MODULE_HERE}
```